# Tracing my installed application on android

Tags: android

After successful installation of an in house application on android version 2.3.1 tablet, I need to see the following:

1. Device manager (or program manager) where this app is installed
   and the app details?
2. Task manager to monitor CPU usage (is there an in built android TM or
   do I need to install appl to see the
   CPU usage)
3. Set/Unset Screen resolution (like Graphic display in windows)

Comment: are you using samsung galaxy tab?

Comment: One thing do you want to do this mannually or programatically...?

Comment: Any which way is easier (I guess when you say manually its through GUI)